# How to run application with parameters and variables in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

Hello i need to run application with parameters. When I run such code all work nice:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Program Files\\LM\\lm.exe', '-addFolder D:\\OLya\\1537627358160\\`)
```

But when i want change path D:\OLya\1537627358160\ to variable its dont work. Like this:

```
import subprocess
FOLDER = 'D:\\OLya\\1537627358160\\'
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Program Files\\LM\\lm.exe', '-addFolder'+FOLDER])
```

Can somebody help with fix? Need to do few variable as parameters which need for run program.

Comment: probably a typo? you missed a space between `-addFolder` and your directory

Comment: Its dont work. I did this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `'-addFolder'+FOLDER`, there's no space between the `-addFolder` option and its value, which ends up being interpreted as a random string not understood as an option by your command.

You're basically running this line:

```
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Program Files\\LM\\lm.exe', '-addFolderD:\\OLya\\1537627358160\\`)
```

Just add a space: after the flag: `'-addFolder ' + FOLDER`.

Even better, you can give the different parameters as elements of the list passed to `Popen`:

```
subprocess.Popen([
    'C:\\Program Files\\LM\\lm.exe',
    '-addFolder',
    FOLDER
])
```